# Outer loop only runs once :(

Tags: nested

My code is of course below. I'm just trying to see if my nesting is working, so I'm printing a string so that each character should correspond to an iteration of the loop at that level. So '1' outside of the loop, '2' is the first loop, '3' is the inner loop.

```
var testing = function(){
    string = '1';
    for(var count = 0; count < 10; count++){
        string += '2';
        for(var count = 0; count < 10; count++){
            string += '3'
        };
        string += '2'
    }
    string += '1'
    return string;
} 

document.write(testing())
```

the page reads: 12333333333321
but I want it to have '2{...}2' 10 times instead of just the once. The outer loop is only running once.

Comment: Wow I just realized this as soon as I typed it up. I'm still a huge noob. The count variable is global? is this why? I changed one of the counts to mount and it worked! then i saw your comment : ) programming is...fun

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the scope of a variable declared with `var` is the current execution context (in your case the function) and if you redeclare a variable it doesn't lose it's value.

Add this together and your inner loop and outer loop are both using the same `count` variable.

Solution: rename one of them.